# .NET C# setting the value of a field defined by a lambda selector

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, generics, variable-assignment

I have a generic class HierarchicalBusinessObject. In the constructor of the class I pass a lambda expression that defines a selector to a field of TModel.

```
protected HierarchicalBusinessObject
    (Expression<Func<TModel,string>> parentSelector)
```

A call would look like this, for example:

```
public class WorkitemBusinessObject : 
    HierarchicalBusinessObject<Workitem,WorkitemDataContext>
{
    public WorkitemBusinessObject() 
       : base(w => w.SuperWorkitem, w => w.TopLevel == true)
    { }
}
```

I am able to use the selector for read within the class. For example:

```
sourceList.Select(_parentSelector.Compile()).Where(...
```

Now I am asking myself how I could use the selector to set a value to the field. 
Something like
selector.Body() .... Field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you pass an Expression<>. You could just pass a Func<TModel,string> as selector and Action<TModel,string> to set a value to a property:

```
protected HierarchicalBusinessObject(Action<TModel,string> parentSetter);
```

```
public class WorkitemBusinessObject :  
    HierarchicalBusinessObject 
{ 
public WorkitemBusinessObject()  
       : base( (WorkItem w, string s) => {w.Name = s;}) 
    { } 
}
```

And use it like so:

```
sourceList.ForEach(w => _parentSetter(w, "NewName"));
```

Comment: I understand your proposal. Thanks. 
But then I have to pass two expressions, one for setting and the second for getting. This is somewhat redundant, since it is the same field. I was hoping to pass just "this is the field" and implement the setter and getter generically.

Comment: By the way I am using Expressions, because I need them for Linq query construction (entity framework).